# How to keep values in a list in Python within a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

Good Evening,

I'm trying to make this Roll Dice simulation in Python. And the code gives me a % of the doubles it gets. I want to keep those percentages on a list. I have the following code, but it gives me this error:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

How can I assign those values to a List where I want to keep them? This could be a silly question, but I'm learning about lists and loops. Thank you.

**SIMULATION OF A ROLL DICE**

````
def rollOneDie():
    thisFace = randrange(1,7)
    return thisFace

nDoubles = 0
list1 = []
rounds = 100

for i in range(3):
    for roundNumber in range(rounds):
        die1 = rollOneDie()
        die2 = rollOneDie()

        if (die1 == die2):
            nDoubles = nDoubles + 1
            print die1, die2
        percent = (nDoubles * 100.0) / rounds
    list1.append[i] = percent

print 'Out of', rounds, 'you rolled', nDoubles, 'doubles, or', percent, '%'```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
list1.append[i] = percent
```

To

```
list1.append(percent)
```

Comment: As an alternative, current syntax can be preserved by initializing list1 as a dictionary instead.

Comment: @KarlOlufsen I don't know yet how to do that.

Comment: @Ivan Parra list1 = [] this piece declares list1 to be a list. list1 = {} and this would be a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

I've updated the code thanks to the Keatinge contribution and also I've found some errors.

This is the final code and it makes the thing I wanted to.

```
from random import randrange

def rollOneDie():
    thisFace = randrange(1,7)
    return thisFace

nDoubles = 0
list1 = []
rounds = raw_input('How many times do you want to throw the dice per simulation? ')
rounds = int(rounds)
simulations = raw_input('How many simulations do you want to do? ')
simulations = int(simulations)

for i in range(simulations):
    nDoubles = 0
    for roundNumber in range(rounds):
        die1 = rollOneDie()
        die2 = rollOneDie()

        if (die1 == die2):
            nDoubles = nDoubles + 1
    percent = (nDoubles * 100.0) / rounds
    print 'Out of', rounds, 'you rolled', nDoubles, 'doubles, or', percent, '%'
    print percent
    list1.append(percent)

print list1
```

The print lines are there just for checking if the outputs were right.